# How do you say "It's the questions we can't answer that teach us the most." in Latin?

Tags: classical-latin

A tad nuance is fine, as long as the original meaning is there.

Would appreciate it if someone took time to do this. Don't be obliged though..

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest:

> Maxime nos docent eae quaestiones, ad quas respondere non possumus.

Or, less literally:

> Ex eis quaestionibus maxime discimus, ad quas quod respondeamus non habemus.

Because I google'd a little and noticed that *quod respondeamus* is a really popular phrase, occurring in lots of variations, e.g. *ad hanc quaestionem adhuc nihil certi est, quod respondeamus* or *vix habebimus quod respondeamus* or *quod respondeamus, facile est in promtu* etc.

Comment: I like these suggestions. One question though: Is *quaestio* a good choice here? It sounds more like "search" or "investigation" than "question" to me, but those ideas can work well in this context. Depends on what the OP is after.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta res ita mihi esse videtur: Si te rogaverim, quo modo stellae formentur, ad hoc **rogatum** meum tibi licuerit repondere; sin apud conventum astronomorum de stellarum formatione quaesitum sit, ad illam **quaestionem** astronomis licuerit respondere.

Comment: Assentior! Fortasse vero quaestiones plus quam rogata ad vitam humanam eiusque problemata gravia attinent. De his credo rogatorem nobis scribentem cogitasse.

Answer (score 3):

If you're OK with a somewhat gnomic translation which isn't very literal but may nevertheless get at the intended sense, you could go with something like

> Plurima ex ignotis noscimus.

This is literally "It's from unknown things that we come to know / learn the most". It leaves out the "questions" and might require some more explanation than a more faithful translation would, but maybe it's useful for your purposes.